# Multiple assignment of variables in coffee

Tags: javascript, python, coffeescript

Can I assign multiple variables in `coffee` like in `python`:

`a, b, c = 'this', 'is', 'variables'`

`print c`  >>>variables

Comment: There is always the coffee script website which allows you to try simple snippets. For you case: http://goo.gl/pRqaWS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with `[a, b, c] = ['this', 'is', 'variables']`.

Comment: awesome, thanks
`_ref = ['this', 'is', 'variables'], a = _ref[0], b = _ref[1], c = _ref[2];`

Comment: @qm69 this is what coffeescript compiles to.